# Periodic SSL cert errors

Tags: bug, ssl

Once or twice a day I get this error, it persists for 5 minutes or so and eventually resolves itself:

> The owner of stackoverflow.com has configured their website improperly. To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected to this website.
>
> This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that Firefox only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not possible to add an exception for this certificate.
>
> Learn more…
>
> stackoverflow.com uses an invalid security certificate.
>
> The certificate is only valid for the following names:
>     qa.sockets.stackexchange.com, chat.sockets.stackexchange.com, mobile.sockets.stackexchange.com, stacksnippets.net
>
> Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

The error happens sometimes when I click a link, or when I try to submit a comment, that fails and I hit refresh and get that error.

Comment: Is that on a page load, so when you visit a new question? Or when an AJAX call takes place? I've personally not seen this on Chrome but i don't use FF often. Do you have the same issue with other browsers?

Comment: How are you connecting to the site? Over http? Directly with https? What pages show this issue? Any links?

Comment: Already "connected" via https. I mean, I have a stackoverflow.com page open in front of me; https is basically connectionless. The whole domain stackoverflow.com (how could the path part of the URL at make a difference - the error comes before the request headers are sent.)

Comment: This happens as soon as you try accessing Stack Overflow? Are you trying to access over http or https?

Comment: I've loaded the site on FF 55.0.2 - browsed around, couldn't reproduce. Do you have any add-ons/plug-ins/extensions installed that might cause this? Did you try disabling them and see if you can reproduce?

Comment: https, I get the broken padlock icon and everything.

Comment: But only sometimes? Not always?

Comment: yeah, it's not doing it now, only sometimes. like 5 minutes out of every 3 hours. perhaps one of the ip addresses I get for stackoverflow.com is actually not serving that domain name.

Comment: Does it ever happen here on meta.so ?

Comment: Not yet. not for other stackexchange domains either, just stackoverflow.com

Comment: A couple of more questions - are you behind a proxy? Does this reproduce in other browsers?

Comment: no proxy, I think I tried a different browser a couple of times.  will try again next time.

Comment: What's the exact URL you are at when this happens?  (Please cut and paste from the URL bar?)

Comment: when it's not working this url is sufficient to demonstrate `https://stackovrflow.com/` I'm in New Zealand.

Comment: @Zealand Can you see what IP address the browser resolves to and the 
values of any x-* response headers (x-cache, x-request-guid, x-served-by, x-timer especially). Looks like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor shows how to view the headers and remote address the browser used.

Comment: it looks more  like a naughty DNS server to me,  have pasted headers collected using wget... I was too slow to get the headers from the bad server.

Comment: stackoverflow.com seems to have a DNS TTL of 5 minutes, which correlates well to the duration of the outages.

Comment: Apparently Bing.com had the same error intermittently but I haven't seen it recently. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/forum/bing_websearch-bing_unex_search/httpswwwbingcom-and-firefox/af1f5374-16df-4591-a3e5-fc01f2e4f03c?auth=1